# Using magento's default Import Export Product . Is there way to make the attributes mandatory for import

Tags: magento2, importexport

I want to make the categories attribute column mandatory when importing the product csv.Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Magento's default Import Export Product feature allows you to make attributes mandatory for import.

To make an attribute mandatory, you can set its "Mandatory" field to "Yes" in the Magento Admin Panel. Here's how to do it:

1. Go to "Stores" -> "Attributes" -> "Product" in the Magento Admin Panel.
2. Find the attribute that you want to make mandatory and click on it.
3. Scroll down to the "Advanced Attribute Properties" section.
4. Set the "Mandatory" field to "Yes" and save the attribute.

Once you have set an attribute as mandatory, Magento's Import Export Product feature will require that attribute to be present in the import file. If the attribute is missing, the import process will fail and Magento will display an error message indicating that the attribute is required.

Note that setting an attribute as mandatory will only affect future imports. If you have already imported products without the mandatory attribute, you will need to update those products to include the attribute before you can save any changes to them.